# Sencha Touch: Toolbar to hold mulitple buttons and overflow if more than a certain number

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Suppose in a Sencha Touch form I have 3 or 5 action(not navigation) buttons such as

- Save
- Delete
- Cancel
- Print
- Download

I wish to show these buttons in a bottom bar on every forms to maintain consistency.
They will have only the icons displayed in the portrait mode and icon+text in case of landscape mode.

The thing I want to know is that

1. Is there any available `component` or `plugin` using which I can show these form buttons the way I have mentioned above?
2. In the portrait mode, I just want to show 3 buttons and then show a `More` button (3 vertical dots) on the click of which the rest of the buttons will be displayed. So technically it should handle `overflow` of buttons if more than a certain number. 
   For eg. think of the `tabs` in Sencha ExtJs, where if you open several tabs after a certain number a dropdown will come on the screen to view the rest of the tabs. I want something similar to this.

I could find examples with bottom button bar but they dont fulfill by requirements.

Can anyone guide me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this:

1.) Bind a event for Viewport:
    For example:

```
In app.js: 


Ext.Viewport.on({
   orientationchange: function(viewport, newOrientation) {
       if(newOrientation == 'landscape') {
          // make change to button like wise u want.
          // That is , your button icon + Text.
          // your code for landscape mode.
       }
       else {
          // your code for portrait mode.
       }
   }
});
```

2.) You can create a `modal` panel on click of More button and put extra buttons in that panel.Use showBy method, and pass the button's object in that method.

For example:

```
showBy(btn)
```

check this out for more info: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-showBy